# WPF - converting Bitmap to ImageSource

Tags: c#, wpf, bitmap, type-conversion, imagesource

I need to convert a `System.Drawing.Bitmap` into `System.Windows.Media.ImageSource` class in order to bind it into a HeaderImage control of a WizardPage (Extended WPF toolkit).
The bitmap is set as a resource of the assembly I write.
It is being referenced like that:

```
public Bitmap GetBitmap
{
   get
   {
      Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(Resources.my_banner);
      return bitmap;
   }
}

public ImageSource HeaderBitmap
{
   get
   {
      ImageSourceConverter c = new ImageSourceConverter();
      return (ImageSource)c.ConvertFrom(GetBitmap);
   }
}
```

The converter was found by me [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/621920/How-to-convert-Bitmap-to-ImageSource). I get a NullReferenceException at

```
return (ImageSource) c.ConvertFrom(Resources.my_banner);
```

How can I initialize ImageSource in order to avoid this exception? Or is there another way?
I want to use it afterwards like:

```
<xctk:WizardPage x:Name="StartPage" Height="500" Width="700"
                 HeaderImage="{Binding HeaderBitmap}" 
                 Enter="StartPage_OnEnter"
```

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Comment: See here: [What is a NullReferenceException and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4660142/1136211)

Answer (score 51):

For others, this works:

```
// If you get 'dllimport unknown'-, then add 'using System.Runtime.InteropServices;'
[DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
public static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);

public ImageSource ImageSourceFromBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
{
    var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
    try
    {
        return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
    }
    finally { DeleteObject(handle); }
}
```

Comment: You are my hero. Used this to make an extension for the Bitmap class and it worked fantastic. Nice work.

Comment: @ARidder101 I'm sure I got this from someone else fwiw.

Comment: This approach gives very low quality transparency. Mike Strobel's answer below (https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261562/418362) is much better and does not require any interop.

Comment: Let me know what happen when I didn't call DeleteObject(handle). I've had a problem about this. thank you.

Comment: back in .NET 2.0 days on windows XP, there was a limit of 10.000 handles that couild be opened at the same time. The machine froze when that limit was reached. - So not calling the deletes, means you'll leak a handle. .NET properbly cleans it up somewhere, but you'll most likely get a performance hit.'

Answer (score 32):

For the benefit of searchers, I created a quick converter based on a this more [detailed solution](http://www.shujaat.net/2010/08/wpf-images-from-project-resource.html).

No problems so far.

```
using System;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;

namespace XYZ.Helpers
{
    public class ConvertBitmapToBitmapImage
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Takes a bitmap and converts it to an image that can be handled by WPF ImageBrush
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="src">A bitmap image</param>
        /// <returns>The image as a BitmapImage for WPF</returns>
        public BitmapImage Convert(Bitmap src)
        {
            MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
            ((System.Drawing.Bitmap)src).Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            BitmapImage image = new BitmapImage();
            image.BeginInit();
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            image.StreamSource = ms;
            image.EndInit();
            return image;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You are a god to me today

Comment: I like this.I like this.

Answer (score 14):

I do not believe that `ImageSourceConverter` will convert from a `System.Drawing.Bitmap`.  However, you can use the following:

```
public static BitmapSource CreateBitmapSourceFromGdiBitmap(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    if (bitmap == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("bitmap");

    var rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, bitmap.Width, bitmap.Height);

    var bitmapData = bitmap.LockBits(
        rect,
        ImageLockMode.ReadWrite,
        PixelFormat.Format32bppArgb);

    try
    {
        var size = (rect.Width * rect.Height) * 4;

        return BitmapSource.Create(
            bitmap.Width,
            bitmap.Height,
            bitmap.HorizontalResolution,
            bitmap.VerticalResolution,
            PixelFormats.Bgra32,
            null,
            bitmapData.Scan0,
            size,
            bitmapData.Stride);
    }
    finally
    {
        bitmap.UnlockBits(bitmapData);
    }
}
```

This solution requires the source image to be in Bgra32 format; if you are dealing with other formats, you may need to add a conversion.

Answer (score 14):

dethSwatch - Thank you for your answer above!  It helped tremendously!  After implementing it I was getting the desired behavior but I found I was getting a memory/handle issue in another section of my program.  I changed the code as follows, making it a little more verbose and the issue went away.  Thank you again!

```
    [DllImport("gdi32.dll", EntryPoint = "DeleteObject")]
    [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
    public static extern bool DeleteObject([In] IntPtr hObject);

    public ImageSource ImageSourceForBitmap(Bitmap bmp)
    {
        var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
        try
        {
            ImageSource newSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());

            DeleteObject(handle);
            return newSource;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            DeleteObject(handle);
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: A bit more pretty variant of your :)

```
var handle = bmp.GetHbitmap();
try {
    return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(handle, IntPtr.Zero, Int32Rect.Empty, BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
} catch {
    return null;
} finally {
    Win32.DeleteObject(handle);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

```
void Draw()
{
    System.Drawing.Bitmap bmp = new Bitmap();
    ...
    Image img = new Image();
    img.Source = BitmapToImageSource(bmp)
 }


private BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(System.Drawing.Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memory.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();
        return bitmapimage;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The simpliest solution for me:

```
ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
var bitmap = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("pic1.bmp");
Bitmap bitmap = new System.Drawing.Bitmap(image);//it is in the memory now
var bitmapSource = Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHBitmap(bitmap.GetHbitmap(),IntPtr.Zero,Int32Rect.Empty,BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
myBrush.ImageSource = bitmapSource;
cover.MainGrid.Background = myBrush;
cover.Show();
bitmap.Dispose();
```

Comment: I believe the hande from GetHbitmap should be freed.