# How to convert icon (Bitmap) to ImageSource?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a button and an image named as image1 in my wpf app. I want add image source of the image1 from a file icon of a location or file path. Here is my code:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.IO;
using System.Drawing;

namespace WpfApplication2
{
    public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Icon ico = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe");
            image1.Source = ico.ToBitmap();
        }
    }
}
```

And the error is saying

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Drawing.Bitmap' to
>   'System.Windows.Media.ImageSource'

How to solve this problem?

Comment: This may help: http://stackoverflow.com/a/26261562/424129

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solution suggested by Farhan Anam will work, but it's not ideal: the icon is loaded from a file, converted to a bitmap, saved to a stream and reloaded from the stream. That's quite inefficient.

Another approach is to use the `System.Windows.Interop.Imaging` class and its [`CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.interop.imaging.createbitmapsourcefromhicon%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
private ImageSource IconToImageSource(System.Drawing.Icon icon)
{
    return Imaging.CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon(
        icon.Handle,
        new Int32Rect(0, 0, icon.Width, icon.Height),
        BitmapSizeOptions.FromEmptyOptions());
}

private void Button_Click_1(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    using (var ico = System.Drawing.Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(@"C:\WINDOWS\system32\notepad.exe"))
    {
        image1.Source = IconToImageSource(ico);
    }
}
```

Note the `using` block to dispose the original icon after you converted it. Not doing this will cause handle leaks.

Comment: Yeah I thought so... +1 :)

Comment: Note: CreateBitmapSourceFromHIcon must be called on the GUI thread. Otherwise there will throw an exception.

Answer (score 6):

The error you get is because you try to assign a bitmap as the source of an image. To rectify that, use this function:

```
BitmapImage BitmapToImageSource(Bitmap bitmap)
{
    using (MemoryStream memory = new MemoryStream())
    {
        bitmap.Save(memory, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
        memory.Position = 0;
        BitmapImage bitmapimage = new BitmapImage();
        bitmapimage.BeginInit();
        bitmapimage.StreamSource = memory;
        bitmapimage.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
        bitmapimage.EndInit();

        return bitmapimage;
    }
}
```

like this:

```
image1.Source = BitmapToImageSource(ico.ToBitmap());
```

Comment: Thanks Farhab Anam. Your code has given me the solution. Thanks a lot. :)

Comment: hello again. I am having a image with a black background in my image1 control. Can i change the background color from black to white? thanks.