# How do I convert a System.Drawing.Image to a WPF Image

Tags: vb.net

```
Dim classSymbol As Byte() = ConvertBase64ToByteArray(CheckSheetDetailObj.ClassSymbol)
Dim myimage As System.Drawing.Image
Dim ms As System.IO.MemoryStream = New System.IO.MemoryStream(classSymbol)
myimage = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(ms)
```

I need to convert `myimage` which is of type `System.Drawing.Image` to `System.Windows.Control.Image`

Comment: [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26260654/wpf-converting-bitmap-to-imagesource) should provide all the information you need to create an `ImageSource` from a `Bitmap` object and you can create your `Image` from that.

Comment: Why would you need to generate a `System.Drawing.Image` when you actually need a BitmapSource? Do that directly. Note that a `System.Drawing.Image` is a graphic object, not a Control as the WPF Image Control. You cannot *convert* the former to the latter. Just assign the `Source` property.

Comment: Can you Please elaborate @Jimi

Comment: I have converted it to bitmap image now

Answer (score 1):

If you want to create a graphic object from a byte array encoded as Base64, then assign the resulting bitmap to a WPF Image Control, you just need a MemoryStream.
You don't need to add a reference to `System.Drawing` at all.

In any case, you don't *convert* a graphic object to a Control, you assign a graphic object to a Control that can present bitmap graphic contents.

You can generate a new [BitmapImage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage), set its [BitmapImage.StreamSource](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.media.imaging.bitmapimage.streamsource) to a MemoryStream object and assign the BitmapImage to an Image Control's [Source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.controls.image.source) Property:

```
SomeImage.Source = BitmapImageFromBase64([Some Base64 string])

' [...]

Private Function BitmapImageFromBase64(base64 As String) As BitmapImage
    Dim bitmap = New BitmapImage()
    bitmap.BeginInit()
    bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad
    bitmap.StreamSource = New MemoryStream(Convert.FromBase64String(base64))
    bitmap.EndInit()
    Return bitmap
End Function
```

If you don't have an existing Image Control, you can create one on the fly, then add it to a Container.
For example, a WrapPanel:

```
Dim newImage As New Image With {
    .Source = BitmapImageFromBase64([Some Base64 string]),
    .Width = 100,
    .Height = 100,
    .Margin = New Thickness(5, 5, 0, 0)
}
' Of course use the reference of an existing WrapPanel
wrapPanel.Children.Add(newImage)
```