# setting menuItem icon in style

Tags: wpf

In my DataContext I'm setting a BitmapImage e.g.

```
Image = new BitmapImage(uri);
```

In my style I have

```
<Setter Property="Icon" Value="{Binding Image, Mode=OneWay}" />
```

However the menuItem shows the uri as a string where the icon should be.
Any idea what I'm missing

Comment: You need to convert to an actual `ImageSource` see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26261562/4610605)

Comment: @FelixD. BitmapImage is already an ImageSource.

Answer (score 0):

Not much of an answer but I was able to work around this using the Loaded event and setting the the Icons image in the handler.

```
    void MenuItem_OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var menuItem = (MenuItem)sender;
        if (menuItem.DataContext is OptionMenuItemViewModel x)
            menuItem.Icon = new Image { Source = new BitmapImage(x.ImageUri) };
    }
```

With the following XMAL

```
    <MenuItem Header="_Database" ItemsSource="{Binding DataBaseMenuItemViewModels}" >
                <MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle >
                    <Style TargetType="MenuItem" >
                        <EventSetter Event="Loaded" Handler="MenuItem_OnLoaded"/>
                        <Setter Property="Header" Value="{Binding Path=Title}" />
                        <Setter Property="ToolTip" Value="{Binding Path=ToolTip}" />
                        <Setter Property="Command" Value="{Binding Path=Command}" />
                        <Setter Property="CommandParameter" Value="{Binding Path=Message}" />
                    </Style>
                </MenuItem.ItemContainerStyle>
            </MenuItem>
```

However, I sure would like to know why the obvious didn't work.